# Schemacrawler ignore schema that can't be accessed

Tags: java, database, schema, database-metadata, schemacrawler

I am currently using [Schemacrawler](http://schemacrawler.sourceforge.net/) to gather information about various databases.

The issue I am having is that the user which the application runs under doesn't have access to every database. If I attempt to retrieve the list of schemas:

```
SchemaCrawlerOptions schemaCrawlerOptions = new SchemaCrawlerOptions();
schemaCrawlerOptions.setSchemaInfoLevel(SchemaInfoLevel.minimum());
schemaCrawlerOptions.setTableTypes(new TableType[] { TableType.table });

Database database = SchemaCrawlerUtility.getDatabase(connection, schemaCrawlerOptions);
database.getSchemas()
```

... a SchemaCrawlerException is thrown (The server principal "..." is not able to access the database "..." under the current security context.). Is there a way to get only the databases that are accessible (without having to explicitly declare each schema name)?

Comment: Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7923424/using-java-schemacrawler-why-is-it-scanning-every-table-in-my-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the exception you are getting, I am going to assume that you are using SQL Server. You need to set a schema inclusion rule. You can add this to your code snippet above:

```
schemaCrawlerOptions.setSchemaInclusionRule(new InclusionRule("schema_name.dbo.*", ""));
```

Comment: I had thought about that, but was just checking that I wasn't configuring something incorrectly. Thanks.